# Unrecognised selector sent to instance - method exists

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This is the code i have:

```
UIImage *originalImage = [dictionary objectForKey:@"OriginalImage"];
UIImage *resizedImage = [originalImage imageScaledToFitSize:CGSizeMake(1024,1024)];
```

Then `imageScaledToFitSize` is a big method which exists, and which it's aware of (otherwise i'd be getting a warning).

The second line gives me a crash and this error:

```
-[NSPathStore2 imageScaledToFitSize:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11c660
2012-03-04 11:23:18.207 Journal[7935:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSPathStore2 imageScaledToFitSize:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11c660'
```

Comment: it seems like you store the path of the image in the dictionary and not the image itself

Comment: Post `imageScaledToFitSize:` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure dictionary is returning a `UIImage` object and not a path to an image?  The exception seems to indicate this (`NSPathStore2`)

Answer (score 0):

so, you declared the method `imageScaledToFitSize:` for all `UIImage`,
but are you sure that *originalImage* is pointing to a `UIImage` when you get your object from your `dictionary`?

try this:

```
   UIImage *originalImage = [dictionary objectForKey:@"OriginalImage"];
   if ([originalImage.class isSubclassOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
       UIImage *resizedImage = [originalImage imageScaledToFitSize:CGSizeMake(1024,1024)];
   }else{
       // NSLog(@"%@", [UIImage class]); // OLD
       // NEW EDIT:
       NSLog(@"%@", originalImage.class);
   }
```

Comment: I got the NSLog, which is `UIImage`.

Comment: But the exception clearly says that you are calling `imageScaledToFitSize` on a `NSPathStore2` object?

Comment: ...and if you get the log, then surely originalImage is not an UIImage